# What is the exact definition of the adjoint state in Neural ODE's?

Tags: neural-networks, neural-odes

i am reading the famous article named “Neural Ordinary Differential Equations” by David Duvenaud (2018)
I have come across this definition of the adjoint state (page 2):

$$a(t) = \frac{\mathrm dL}{\mathrm dz}(t)$$

I don't understand what this notation exactly means. Is it the directional derivative of L with respect to the vector z(t)?
Could someone give me the exact definition of this quantity? I tried several interpretations myself, in order to derive the formula for da/dt, but none match the formula in the article (also page 2).

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct.  The adjoint appears to be the gradient of the loss where the derivatives are taken with respect to the components of $\mathbf{z}(t)$.

$L$ seems to map vectors to scalars (states of the system $\mathbf{z}$ to loss values).  That means $L : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$.  Taking derivative with respect to the input (at least from the context) means that $\partial L / \partial \mathbf{z}(t)$ is a vector.

Writing this out more explicitly,

$$ \mathbf{a}(t)_j = \dfrac{\partial L}{\partial \mathbf{z}_j(t)}$$

Since the state is a function of time, the adjoint will take different values at different times.

Comment: Thank you so much!